# Zero -dimensional commutative semiprimitive rings

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, prime-ideals

A commutative ring $R $ with 1 is called **semiprimitive** if its Jacobson radical is the zero ideal. Is there any characterization for zero-dimensional semiprimitive commutative rings?

Comment: Since this will include all finitely generated algebras over a field which are integral domains (a class which this site is mostly concerned about), a non-trivial characterization would mean most of us can go home.

Answer (score 2):

These are exactly the zero-dimensional *reduced* commutative rings (a.k.a. "absolutely flat rings"). Clearly semiprimitive rings are reduced.

[EDIT: what follows is correct but much too complicated. See the comment by Luc Guyot.]

<strike>Conversely, assume $R$ is zero-dimensional and reduced. For every $\mathfrak{p}\in\mathrm{Spec}(R)$, $R_\mathfrak{p}$ is local, zero-dimensional and reduced, hence $\mathfrak{p}R_\mathfrak{p}=0$ (in other words, $R_\mathfrak{p}$ is a field). So if $x$ is in the Jacobson radical of $R$, then $x$ is zero in every $R_\mathfrak{p}$, hence $x=0$.</strike>

Comment: If $R$ is zero-dimensional, then its primes are maximal so that the nilradical of $R$ coincides with the Jacobson radical of $R$. For this reason, I don't understand the need for "Conversely". Am I missing something?

Comment: @LucGuyot: You are right!

Answer (score 2):

Several nice characterizations for these rings are worked out as Exercise 4.15 in Lam's book "Exercises in Classical Ring Theory."  These include (for commutative rings):

(A) $R$ is reduced and $K$-dim $R$=0.

(B) $R$ is von Neumann regular.

(C) The localizations of $R$ at its maximal ideals are all fields.